# Loading Excel (Office 365) data from a console application

Tags: c#, excel, office365

Trying to load data excel in a console application. I have excel from Office 365 version, the connection strings from various questions in SO are not working. Could someone please share the connection string and sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Is is not able to connect the Excel on the SharePoint directly using database connection.

You may consider using the **Microsoft Graph REST** to get the contents of online documents. Here is an example that get the **used range** from one spreadsheet on Office 365:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/workbook/worksheets/{id|sheetName}/UsedRange
```

To use the Microsoft Graph, we need to register the app first and then authenticate the app. You can refer [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization) about more detail.